# Peer to Peer solution for LAN over Internet

Tags: windows-xp, vpn, lan, emulation

I need to emulate a LAN between some machines over the internet to play some LAN only games. I remember that there was software that could do this, but don't remember what it was called.

Anyone heard of this, or know of similar solutions that won't require a lot of work? The game is fun, but not fun enough to bother with setting up a VPN server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only easy-to-set-up one I can think of is Hamachi:
https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/

That's the one you meant, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 0):

[teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com) lets you build vpns as well. (hamachis is good nevertheless)

Comment: Really? I can't find such feature on their site, it seems to be more dedicated to remote desktop. I didn't know about it.

Comment: really. checkout their client, you will get a "vpn" option in it. you can also check their manual at http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_manual.pdf in section 9.3